# How to run TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015 without require() or requireJS

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, requirejs, bundling-and-minification

I've setup a new web project where I wanted to begin working/learning TypeScript. This project while an empty c#.net web project is not using MVC, angular, etc. It is just plain vanilla html and Ts. Everything was running smooth until I started setting up modules (classes, interfaces etc.) Once I started exporting and importing the modules I began receiving in the dev tools the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Looking at the actual js file I can see it is wrapping the body of the file in a require(). 
This project is small and I don't want to setup requireJs if possible. Is there are way to disable the Ts compiler in VS to not insert the require() function? node.js is not being used and within the project properties I have switched the Modules system from CommonJS to Es2015.

Or am I totally missing something here and should be bundling these files?

I am declaring the exports and imports as:

interface.ts

```
import  {Category }  from './enums';

interface ICar {
    id: number;
    make: string;
    model: string;
    vin?: string;
    mileage?: number;
    category: Category;
}

export { ICar }
```

enum.ts

```
enum Category { Antique, Sportscar, Truck, SUV, Sedan };

export { Category };
```

and at the top of my main file app.ts I reference the modules

```
import { Category } from './enums'; 
import { ICar } from './interfaces';
```

Once compiled the js output in my main file app.js contains this at the header

```
"use strict";
var enums_1 = require("./enums");
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: When you say you get the error in the "devtools" are you talking visual studio or are you talking about in a browser?

Comment: @Chris the error appears in the console portion of the Chrome Dev Tools.  So instead of seeing the actual output from a console.log etc. I get an error and the script stops running. Visual Studio compiles the Ts fine

Comment: My guess is that your compiled typeScript isn't getting bundled together. Browsers don't run modules without having some kind of module loader with it. Many solutions exists, systemJS, WebPack, Gulp... even .net's own script bundler. You need to either have a helper load the modules or you need to make all of your modules into one script.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up typescript in visual studio project like this:
[image]

Then if you never use export or import, you will be able to work. For proper files chaining (when bundlig all together) don't forget to add your references at the top of your ts files:

```
/// <reference path="path/mytool.class.ts" />
```