# "The build task could not find node.exe which is required to run the TypeScript compiler." occurred after update Boostrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, visual-studio-2015, bootstrap-4, nuget-package

I developed an ASP.Net MVC web application and It's almost completed. After That, I updated Bootstrap through NuGet package manager to Bootstrap latest stable `version 4.3.1` Update was successfully completed. But after the migration following errors are occurred.

```
Error Build:Cannot find name 'Record'.
Error Build:Cannot find name 'undefined'.
```

To solve that I installed `TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015`. Then the above error solved and the following error occurred.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The build task could not find node.exe which is required to run
>   the TypeScript compiler. Please install Node and ensure that the
>   system path contains its location. ABH.SW.HotelManagement

How can I solve this? I tried to google it for the past 2 days but I wasn't able to find any solution

Answer (score 13):

This is the only post for this problem, so I'll do my bit for those who use Bootstrap 4.3.1, TypeScript, and VS2015.

First, once you create the project and are about to install Bootstrap 4.3.1 through NuGet, don't let Visual Studio manage TypeScript Typings for you. Check no.

[image]

Once Bootstrap and stuff is installed, clean the solution: right click on your solution -> clean solution

Next, open NuGet console (Tools → NuGet Package Manager → Package Manager Console), and install TypeScript 3.0 using this command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild -Version 3.0.0
```

Close Visual Studio, open it again, and that's it. Took for me a lot of research to find out that several TypeScript versions cause a lot of conflicts and 3.0 is one of those that actually work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while trying to update to Bootstrap 4 from Visual Studio 2015.  What fixed it for me was installing Typescript 2.2 for Visual Studio 2015 (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.TypeScript22forVisualStudio2015).  You may need to uninstall previous versions of Typescript Tools for VS2015 from Programs and Features.

Answer (score 1):

I think Bootstrap 4.3.1 , Typescript , VS2015 has some issues with each other.
[e.g. 
[Compilation error from Angular and typescript in VS 2015 MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934468/compilation-error-from-angular-and-typescript-in-vs-2015-mvc-project)
]

My scenario in my project got this error

> Error The build task could not find node.exe which is required to run
>   the TypeScript compiler. Please install Node and ensure that the
>   system path contains its location. ACC_Cor...

I'm using VS2017 while other team member that has problem using VS2015 with TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 3.2.2.0 installed

He told me that after map project from source control there is and alert message of something like his typescript version is newer. So after some googling I think you should look in to this link for more information 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17136

[VS2015 - Change TypeScript Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385087/vs2015-change-typescript-version)

[How to run TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015 without require() or requireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751573/how-to-run-typescript-in-visual-studio-2015-without-require-or-requirejs)

**tldr;**

> For Vs2015 + Bootstrap 4.3.1 I solved my issue by

1. Check project property 
   [image]
2. Uninstall Typescript
3. Install Typescript version 3.0 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

[image]